# Make section header in UITableview overlap cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to push down the section header in my tableview to make it overlap the first cell in the section, similar to the way profile pictures appear in the linkedin app on the left:

[image: linkedin app screenshot]

So, if the white view the profile picture is overlapping is the first row in the section, and the profile picture is the section header.

I've tried changing the x coordinate of the frame to a negative value and messing around with the size of the header, all to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

I was just looking at the profile view in the LinkedIn App, and I think if I were to build something similar, I would put all the profile information in the tableHeaderView.  So the header would consist of the following:

- UIImageView (background image)
- UIView (containing profile
  information)
- UIImageView (users profile image)

[image]

Since a UITableView is a subclass of the UIScrollView, you can animate the background image using the delegate method scrollViewDidScroll.  You can then adjust the position of the background image while the tableview scrolls

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *backgroundImage;

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    // 64 is the height of the navigation bar.
    // 110 is the maximum distance I want to move the image down before it starts to move with the table.
    CGFloat offset = MIN(scrollView.contentOffset.y + 64, 110);
    self.backgroundImage.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, offset);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Ryan! Although, I was ideally wanting to replicate this effect for every cell in the table view, not just at the top! For now I've just created a wrapper view inside the cell and made the cell transparent and created the effect inside the confines of the cell. Feels a bit like a workaround though, would be interesting to see if it can be achieved using section headers!

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom view in`viewForHeaderInSection()` where you can define whatever shaped your header needs to be. In your case, circle in the bottom center of a rectangle. And set content to that view.

Change alpha value of the view which you want transparent to be 0 in that custom view. So the undesired portion of header will not be shown on screen.